# "AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'cv2' " error. alraedy installed opencv-contrib-python and others also in different version

Tags: python, numpy, face-recognition

```
import cv2

import numpy as np

import face_recognition

imgRohit = face_recognition.load_image_file('images/Rohit.jpg')

imgRohit = cv2.cvtColor(imgRohit.cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

imgRohit_1 = face_recognition.load_image_file('images/Rohit_1.jpg')

imgRohit_1 = cv2.cvtColor(imgRohit_1.cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

cv2.imshow('Rohit', imgRohit)

cv2.imshow('Rohit_1', imgRohit_1)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: pls review the code, you are missing comma in following lines imgRohit = 
imgRohit = cv2.cvtColor(imgRohit,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
imgRohit_1 = cv2.cvtColor(imgRohit_1,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the dot in `imgRohit = cv2.cvtColor(imgRohit.cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)` between `imgRohit` and `cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB`, It should be a comma.